# Custom Instruction crashing with SIGNAL 4 (Illegal Instruction): RISC-V (32) GNU-Toolchain with QEMU

Tags: c, cpu-architecture, qemu, riscv

I have been wanting to develop and understand the process of creating custom extensions for a large-scale task I have, involving RISC-V compilation using the QEMU emulator. I have been loosely following the below guide: https://chowdera.com/2021/04/20210430120004272q.html - In trying to understand where and how the instruction is parsed, implemented and executed in this way through QEMU. I have edited and created an entry for my R-type instruction, same as up there, however when I try to issue it as an .insn directive in ASM, the following exception is thrown:

'Program stopped with Signal 4 (Illegal Instruction)'

The code that produced this exception:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    static int custom_cube(int addr) 
    {
       int cube;
       asm volatile(".insn r 0x7b, 6, 6, %0, %1, x0" : "=r"(cube) : "r"(addr));
       return cube;
    }

    int main() {
       int a = 3;
       int ret = 0;
       ret = custom_cube((int)&a);
       if(ret == a * a * a) {
           printf("Success");
       }
       else {
           printf("Failed");
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

I have attempted to look into the encoding of the instruction (exactly as the tutorial describes and same opcode and bitfields), to see if there was any conflict, if the helper functions were incorrectly implemented etc, I also rebuilt and configured QEMU after implementation and ran again, reaching the same error, I changed the encoding once again to something different and changed the .insn opcode call accordingly, and attained the same behaviour, even after verifying and type-checking. I am still rather new to the build process of implementing custom RISC-V instructions specifically through QEMU, and would appreciate if there was any input or anything that either I or perhaps this tutorial has neglected to include in this process, a similar guide using the RiscFree IDE had a similar process, (implementing trans and helper functions - then rebuilding QEMU and running), so the fact the Linux kernel is throwing this exception I am still unsure of. Is there something blindingly obvious I might have missed? Should I have rebuilt the entire toolchain and not just QEMU? From what this tutorial had gathered to me, I presumed nothing further was required.

Disassembly under the custom header: With the corresponding source

```
static int custom_cube(int addr)
{
   1018c:       fd010113                addi    sp,sp,-48
   10190:       02812623                sw      s0,44(sp)
   10194:       03010413                addi    s0,sp,48
   10198:       fca42e23                sw      a0,-36(s0)
    int cube;
    asm volatile (
   1019c:       fdc42783                lw      a5,-36(s0)
   101a0:       0c07e7fb                .4byte  0xc07e7fb
   101a4:       fef42623                sw      a5,-20(s0)
       ".insn r 0x7b, 6, 6, %0, %1, x0"
             :"=r"(cube)
             :"r"(addr)
     );
    return cube;
   101a8:       fec42783                lw      a5,-20(s0)
}
   101ac:       00078513                mv      a0,a5
   101b0:       02c12403                lw      s0,44(sp)
   101b4:       03010113                addi    sp,sp,48
   101b8:       00008067                ret
```

(Since it doesn't appear to disassemble under an existing RISC-V instruction, I ((presume)) that I did put it under a free spot? I changed the variation a fair few times and still experienced this, even after validating all other possible overlaps - none were found, so I feel as if it is to do with the implementation or it's call).

UPDATE TO ISSUE: I have since used a different encoding for the instruction
OPCODE = "0110011", FUNCT3 = "111" and FUNCT7 = "0100000".

Upon recompiling QEMU and running this using the .insn directive, QEMU appears to just hang upon decoding the instruction - I am unsure what further implementation is required after using TCG directives.

Comment: If you use a disassembler on your compiled program, does your custom instruction disassemble as some existing instruction?  (Assuming you picked an actually-unused opcode, rebuilding just QEMU sounds fine.  If the instruction is just some ALU operation between registers, nothing else needs to know about it, just the CPU that's actually executing it, not the kernel that loaded the process into memory or even the toolchain, thanks to the existence of `.inst` and a regular machine-code format where the register fields are at consistent places.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Right on - When disassembling through the custom_cube method's header, under the .insn invocation the following returns.
```1019c:       fdc42783                lw      a5,-36(s0)
   101a0:       0c07e7fb                .4byte  0xc07e7fb
   101a4:       fef42623                sw      a5,-20(s0)
       ".insn r 0x7b, 6, 6, %0, %1, x0"
             :"=r"(cube)
             :"r"(addr)
     );
```
The fact that no other instruction appears to be registered under it indicates to me that this was a free slot, but I could be incorrect. (Apologies for the messy formatting!)

Comment: [edit] your question with disassembly, since as you noticed it's a nearly unreadable mess in a comment.  Also, it's not a "method", C doesn't have those or even member functions.  It's a (free) function, at global scope but local to this compilation unit because it's `static`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe it should be under the post now - Apologies for the mis-terminology there

Comment: No worries.  Sounds like you now need to debug your modified copy of QEMU itself, to see what happens when it tries to decode that instruction.  To see if it ever reaches your new code that should recognize that opcode.

Comment: @PeterCordes it appears upon debugging QEMU - it immediately halts and gives yet another sigill - stating an illegal instruction, which gives me the idea that the instruction is somehow not being decoded at all, but I am unsure where else would be required to change before rebuilding to indicate the presence of a new insteuction, seeing as the helpers etc were already in place and 'insn32.decode' was appropriately changed.