# Rebuild QEMU (For RISCV-GNU-TOOLCHAIN)

Tags: c, gnu, qemu, riscv

This is a follow-up from the following question [Custom Instruction crashing with SIGNAL 4 (Illegal Instruction): RISC-V (32) GNU-Toolchain with QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100115/custom-instruction-crashing-with-signal-4-illegal-instruction-risc-v-32-gnu?noredirect=1#comment127395970_72100115) (apologies if I have missed any etiquette points in advance or formatted this in an unsavoury way, as I am still new to posting here). I am using the latest version of the riscv-gnu-toolchain, so I am just wondering what caveats and differences this process will be for this platform.

I was following namely two guides to add custom RISC-V instructions to QEMU - namely https://www.ashling.com/wp-content/uploads/QEMU_CUSTOM_INST_WP.pdf and https://chowdera.com/2021/04/20210430120004272q.html.

After editing qemu/target/riscv/insn32.decode with a free opcode (following Ashling tutorial), and implementing translator function in insn_trans/trans_rvi.c.inc - QEMU hangs when calling the function as an .insn directive (I know this to work - ). Changing opcodes of existing instructions to test if disassembly changes indicated to me that QEMU was not registering the changes I made and that I didn't rebuild/recompile QEMU correctly. I simply ran `make clean`, reconfigured and `make` again in the QEMU directory to rebuild it - Is this the correct way to rebuild QEMU in this toolchain or is there something I missed.

The code to call

```
#include <stdio.h>


static int test_ins(int a, int b) {
        int result;
        asm volatile(".insn r 0x33, 7, 0x20, %0, %1, %2" : "=r"(result) : "r"(a), "r"(b));
        return result;
}


int main() {
        int a, b, result;
        a = 2;
        b = 4;
        result = test_ins(a,b);
        printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Instruction in insn32.decode is as follows:

```
OPCODE = "0110011", FUNCT3 = "111" and FUNCT7 = "0100000".
```

Implementation of aforementioned instruction is as follows:

```
static bool trans_bitcnt(DisasContext *ctx, arg_bitcnt *a)
{
TCGLabel *loop_source1 = gen_new_label();
TCGLabel *loop_source2 = gen_new_label();
TCGv source1, source2, dstval, cntval;
source1 = tcg_temp_local_new();
source2 = tcg_temp_local_new();
dstval = tcg_temp_local_new();
cntval = tcg_temp_local_new();
// Count all the bits set in rs1 and rs2 and put that number in rd
gen_get_gpr(source1, a->rs1);
gen_get_gpr(source2, a->rs2);
tcg_gen_movi_tl(cntval, 0x0);
/* Count the bits that are set in the first register */
gen_set_label(loop_source1);
tcg_gen_andi_tl(dstval, source1, 0x1);
tcg_gen_shri_tl(source1, source1, 0x1);
tcg_gen_add_tl(cntval, cntval, dstval);
tcg_gen_brcondi_tl(TCG_COND_NE, source1, 0x0, loop_source1);
/* Count the bits that are set in the second register */
gen_set_label(loop_source2);
tcg_gen_andi_tl(dstval, source2, 0x1);
tcg_gen_shri_tl(source2, source2, 0x1);
tcg_gen_add_tl(cntval, cntval, dstval);
tcg_gen_brcondi_tl(TCG_COND_NE, source2, 0x0, loop_source2);
 /* Update the destination register with the bits total */
gen_set_gpr(a->rd, cntval);
tcg_temp_free(source1);
tcg_temp_free(source2);
tcg_temp_free(dstval);
tcg_temp_free(cntval);
return true;
}
```

Comment: Your long text is hard to read. I suggest to structure it a bit and use formatting like `code` for code, file names, commands, or lists for the steps you have done. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: don't describe your problem. show the code you have a problem with.

Comment: TL;DR the code is unchanged from that of the problem I linked to previously, the issue is now not the code, it's the process of rebuilding QEMU for this toolchain, that's all I want to know. @stark

Comment: @Bodo edited question for brevity - the code is added link but at this point the issue is not with the code it is with QEMU itself, I just want to know if I am rebuilding it correctly.

Comment: your steps are how I've rebuilt qemu. Are you sure the build had no errors?

Comment: @stark No errors from the build and no abrupt end to the build process each time. I presume calling riscv32-unknown-elf-run would have ran the updated riscv32-softmmu from the rebuild QEMU, but I can see from disassembly that no changes have been registered.

Comment: For further reference I used ./configure --target-list=riscv32-softmmu

Comment: 'make' is enough to rebuild (a make clean and reconfigure are not necessary). Check the usual stuff -- did the 'make' actually succeed and exit with status 0, has the timestamp on the QEMU binary file updated, are you actually running the correct newly rebuilt executable and not some random other one from somewhere else on your system?

Comment: @PeterMaydell I believe it may be because I am not in the right directory or querying the correct makefile, I've just reinstalled the entire riscv-gnu-toolchain right now, made the changes to QEMU, and upon running make now it says 'nothing to be done for 'all'' despite knowingly changing target/riscv

Comment: You don't want to be in any subdirectory to run 'make'. You need to be in the top level directory (that's the top level build dir if you're using a separate build directory, or top level source directory if you're building directly in the source tree). That then builds all of the targets that were enabled when you ran configure.

Comment: Please add all information to the question, don't use comments to provide requested information or clarification. Unfortunately I cannot help with the problem, but it will be easier for everyone if it is not necessary to read all comments to get all details related to your question.

Comment: @PeterMaydell Running make in the QEMU directory yields me that - by top level do you mean the entire toolchain's build? Or just QEMU itself. Apologies for this as I am still trying to toy around with the problem. I presumed it was just an issue with WSL2 and not installing everything correctly but the same behaviour persists on my Linux VM so I am definitely hunched that it is because I am not making in the right directory.

Comment: You're trying to build QEMU, so I mean the top level QEMU directory.

Comment: @PeterMaydell I did so and still to no avail. Could it be to do with how I am using riscv32-unknown-elf-run to run the output files? As I cannot find the standalone qemu-riscv32 when rebuilding the toolchain from scratch.

Comment: I have no idea what the command "riscv32-unknown-elf-run" command is -- it's not part of QEMU. If you have problems with it you should probably ask whoever you got it from. You're building system emulation, so the actual QEMU binary will be "qemu-system-riscv32".